# F# .NET Core 2.1 simple crud app: controllers don't get registered

Tags: f#, .net-core

I am trying to use F# with .NET Core 2.1 to create a simple CRUD application but none of the controllers don't get registered. I see none of the controllers in Swagger and the controller themselves don't start.

I appreciate any help or hint.

Startup.fs

```
namespace SimpleCms

type Startup private () =
    let mutable configuration : IConfigurationRoot = null

    member this.Configuration
        with get () = configuration
        and private set (value) = configuration <- value

    new(env : IHostingEnvironment) as this =
        Startup()
        then 
            let builder =
                ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional = false, reloadOnChange = true)
                    .AddJsonFile(sprintf "appsettings.%s.json" env.EnvironmentName, optional = true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()

            this.Configuration <- builder.Build()

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    member this.ConfigureServices(services : IServiceCollection) =

        services.AddLogging() |> ignore

        services.AddSwaggerGen(fun x ->
            x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info(Title = "SimpleCms", Version = "v1")) |> ignore)
            |> ignore

        services.AddMvcCore() |> ignore

        services.AddMvc() |> ignore

        let container =
            new Container(fun opt -> 

            opt.Scan(fun x -> 
                x.AssemblyContainingType(typeof<Startup>)
                x.Assembly("Dal")
                x.Assembly("Logic")
                x.WithDefaultConventions() |> ignore)

            opt.For<LiteDatabase>().Use(new LiteDatabase("Filename=database.db")) |> ignore

            opt.Populate(services) |> ignore)

        container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>()

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    member this.Configure(app : IApplicationBuilder, env : IHostingEnvironment) =
        app.UseSwagger() |> ignore

        app.UseSwaggerUI(fun x ->
            x.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1") |> ignore) |> ignore

        app.UseMvc(fun x ->
            x.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}") |> ignore) |> ignore
```

HomeController.fs

```
namespace SimpleCms.Controllers

open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

[<Route("")>]
type HomeController() =
    inherit Controller()

    [<Route("")>]
    [<HttpGet>]
    member this.Index() =
        Ok("Hello World!")
```

The complete code

[Repo URL](https://github.com/amir734jj/fsharp-dotnet-core-mvc/tree/59eaaab7fb8e95f24aa44d7eb36c14988f3938a7)

Comment: Repo URL is giving a 404.  What does your "main" look like?

Comment: Good! What was the problem? Post the solution. :)

Comment: @AMieres I meant the problem with the repo link

Comment: Minor point, but you don't need to do `AddMvcCore` if you're already doing `AddMvc`. You should probably also set the compat level: `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2) |> ignore`

Comment: @DavidG No success (https://github.com/amir734jj/fsharp-dotnet-core-mvc/commit/7d861d794b907073454675e9140eed96e4119beb#diff-8aeb7b3d8e00f4f57b1906bd52447abaL41).  Screenshot: https://ibb.co/WcFBZwJ

Comment: Maybe StructureMap doesn't work well with F#

Comment: No, I was just suggesting another improvement. Your problem appears to be the `IPostController`. Remove that and Swagger will pick up the `PostController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the `IPostController` interface. Remove that and Swagger will pick up the `PostController`.

For example:

```
[<Route("api/[controller]")>]
[<ApiController>]
type PostController(logic : IPostLogic) =
    inherit Controller()
    member this.logic = logic

        [<Route("")>]
        [<HttpGet>]
        member this.GetAll() = 
            this.logic.GetAll()

//etc
```

Which makes Swagger show this:

[image]

**Side Note**: For ASP.NET Core 2.1 and above, you shouldn't be specifying the version of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package, your `fsproj` file should contain this instead:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" />
```

Which in turn means you should be using version 2.1.1 of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug`.

Finally, you are using a really old version of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`. I suggest you upgrade that too.

Comment: Actually, there was nothing wrong with StructureMap. I used .NET Reflector and I see that methods are set to `private` instead of public when I use `PostController` implements `IPostController` and that's why controller's method do not get registered. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/vQQx0vD

Comment: yes, there is no way to make interface methods to be `public`, it's always `private`. The only other way I found was making `IPostController` a `class` not an `interface` with `abstract` methods.